# how to find sample data customer username password - magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, password, sample-data

I completed migration from **Magento 1.9.2.4** to **Magento 2.1.6**. I'm just migrating the sample data of magento 1.9.2.4 (I don't create any customer by myself). I'm testing their functionality.

We have seen customer data in Magento 1.9.2.4

`Admin->Customer->Manage Customer`

I need to know the one customer username and password to login in magento 2.1.6 for checking customer data correctly migrated.

After migration I found in customer_entity table

```
email : jack@example.com
password_hash : 4fe96cf8b888c1f20e1726450896940a2cea453128c51fa07539536a4205e12b:t6:1
```

how to decrypt password_hash

Answer (score 1):

You can compare both database password

To

`customer_entity` >> `password_hash` (magento 2)

From

`customer_entity_varchar` >> `value` (Magento 1)

if both your customer's value matched then your migration is successfully done.

Comment: m2 -> `4fe96cf8b888c1f20e1726450896940a2cea453128c51fa07539536a4205e12b:t6:1`, m1 -> `4fe96cf8b888c1f20e1726450896940a2cea453128c51fa07539536a4205e12b:t6`

Comment: :1 append extra in m2 compared to m1, it worked(I have tested like again start migration from the scratch after adding new customer in m1), the same password successfully login in m2 after migration.

Comment: M2 n M1 both using different algorithm to save password

Comment: yup you right! M1 (md5:salt), M2(sha256(salt+pwd):salt:encryption method), I'm wonder how M2 similar to M1 except encryption method

Comment: If my solution help you to resolve your issue then you can mark it so it can help others too

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked out:

You can reset password in admin panel.

- Step1: Navigate to Customers->Manage customers.
- Step2: Select Customer.
- Step3: Select Account Information Tab. Then select Password Management Tab.

Here you can reset password for the customer.

I've found it in [this link](https://www.underwise.com/questions/79178/how-to-find-sample-data-customer-username-password-magento-1-9-2-4)